# Sort a Generic List with orderby or sort

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a Generic List with this structure:

```
        public class Emoticon
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string emoticon_set { get; set; }
    }

    public class Emoticons
    {
        public List<Emoticon> emoticons { get; set; }
    }
```

The List is `Emoticons twitch_emoticons`. No i want to sort the list by the ID. can anyone help me?

Comment: `var sorted = twitch_emoticons.OrderBy(e => e.id);`?

Comment: Programming is not like bending spoons in Matrix - you should not only want, but also try do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the namespace,

```
  using System.Linq;
```

Then try with,

```
var result = twitch_emoticons.OrderBy(res => res.id).ToList();
```

Comment: One thing to note also is that `result` will not be a `List<T>` but rather an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.  This may or may not be an issue.  If it is, you may need to add `.ToList()` at the end.